# Sails Js : sails.sockets.blast returns 2 same events to subscribed clients

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am using the model life cycle callback to emit an event whenever a new instance is created but subscribed clients receive two events instead of one. Any idea how to fix this?

```
afterCreate : function(user, next){
    sails.sockets.blast('users', {verb : 'created', data : user});
    next();
  }
```

And here is my io.socket.on

```
io.socket.on('users', function(msg){
    switch (msg.verb) {
      case "created": 
        console.log("User Created");
        $scope.users.push(msg.data);
        $scope.showAddUserForm(false);
        clearForm()
        $scope.$digest();
        break;
      case "destroyed":
        console.log("User Deleted");
        console.log($scope.users);
        var index = _.findIndex($scope.users,{'id': msg.data.id});
        $scope.users.splice(index,1);
        $scope.showEditOrDeleteUserForm(false);
        $scope.$digest();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The sails.js gitter room is also a good place to chat and get support: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: Are you getting the exact same message twice?  The data is all the same?  And are you certain you're not running `io.socket.on('users')` twice in your front-end code?

Comment: Yes I am certain. I only used io.socket.on once.

Comment: Honest mistake. I found out it's just a fault in my client side. Thank you for the assistance by the way.